# Code works outside of setTimeout, but not inside

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing some light JS/jQuery automation for repetitive work I'm doing on a web application in Chrome. I have three setTimeout functions that are staggered to not overlap. The first two work fine, and the third one seems to execute like it should, but the code doesn't click the file upload button when it is inside setTimeout function.

```
function fileUp(){
    console.log("trying to upload");
    var upload = $('form#my-dropzone.dropzone-button.dz-clickable');
    upload.click();
    console.log(upload);
}

var sku = setSKU();
searchSKU(sku);
var crd = setTimeout(function(){
    clickCard(sku,crd);
}, 3000);
var md = setTimeout(function(){
    mediaTab(md);
}, 5000);
var up = setTimeout(function(){
    fileUp();
}, 9000);
```

However, when I call fileUp() outside of setTimeout, it works perfectly. Why is this happening?

Edit 1:

```
<form action="/imageupload/file" class="dropzone-button dz-clickable" id="my-dropzone">
        <div class="dz-text dz-message">
            <i class="icon-entypo-fix-picture extra-large-entypo-fix-icon box-title-icon"></i><p></p>
            Upload Media
        </div>
        <div id="dropzone-buttons">
            <a href="#" id="start-upload" class="link-button" style="display: none;">Start Upload</a>
            <a href="#" id="close-upload" class="link-button">Close</a><p></p>
            Drop files here or Click to Browse<p></p>
        </div>
        <input>
        <input>
        <input>
    </form>
```

logs:

```
[Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 133ms
VM49737:23 clicked...
[Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 135ms
entityView.js: Render Entity View
VM49737:31 trying to click
jquery-2.0.3.min.js:6 [Violation] 'load' handler took 890ms
VM49737:38 trying to upload
VM49737:41 init [form#my-dropzone.dropzone-button.dz-clickable, prevObject: init(1), context: document, selector: "form#my-dropzone.dropzone-button.dz-clickable"]
```

Comment: Can you post some console.logs?

Comment: It should work, why you think it doesn't?

Comment: What is `upload`? The HTML?

Comment: My guess is that one of your previous functions is modifying the element you're trying to click, so `upload` becomes `undefined` since it doesn't match anything.

Comment: I justtries to replicate in fiddle. With simple function it should work. Like Here. https://jsfiddle.net/ashishkumar9211/xpvt214o/431583/    If it doent work either clickCard(sku,crd); or mediaTab(md); is doing something

Answer (score 0):

```
function fileUp(){
    console.log("trying to upload");
    var upload = $('form#my-dropzone.dropzone-button.dz-clickable');
    upload.click();
    console.log(upload);
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    var sku = setSKU();
    searchSKU(sku);
    var crd = setTimeout(function(){clickCard(sku,crd)}, 3000);
    var md = setTimeout(function(){mediaTab(md)}, 5000);
    var up = setTimeout(function(){fileUp()}, 9000);
});
```

Mabey the form isnt load. user .ready() function should be work

Answer (score 0):

What i would do is try to modify "upload"s background color to make sure the element is properly selected.

```
 $('form#my-dropzone.dropzone-button.dz-clickable').css('background-color', "green");
```

If it does nothing, it means your selector doesn't return anything. To tell you exactly what went wrong here we'd need the html of the element you're trying to select here and your console logs.

Also i'd remove the anonymous function from the third setTimeout and just set directly fileUp as the callback function : `var up = setTimeout(fileUp, 9000);`

Comment: The css change worked, no change when removing anon function. Added html and logs to edit above.

Comment: Judging from the code you added and the result of the css modification, i'd say that the bug we're looking for isn't located anywhere in the code you sent us. My guess is that the click() event is fired properly on your form element, which can means two thing : 1 - Your form has no click handler (or isn't selected properly whithin the handler) 2 - There's something wrong going on within the callback of the form's click handler. Either way, we will also need the js/jquery code for your element's click handler.